# Adding different hyperlink yo php fullcalendar master plugin

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

Differs to the full calendar master database, I added a column called "link" in the event table of the database. My purpose is to allow users to go to different links when they click corresponding day.
I observe other posts/ documentation, still cannot figure out the solution. 
Can someone help me?Below is the code of event.php and my js part in the index.html. I do not change any part of other files of the plugin

```
$json = array();
$request = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";    

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

$result = $bdd->query($request) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fmt(date) {
    return date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
  }

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: '',
    },
    events: "events.php",
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
      window.location = "I need different links fetched from db!!"
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: to be clear, is it that the user should go to a different link, when they click on an _event_, or when they click on a _day_ (i.e. a specific day, but at a time which is not covered by an event)? It's not totally clear, from your description. If you want it based on clicking on an event, simply set the "url" property appropriately on each event object,  as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object, and fullCalendar will do the rest.

Comment: You can use `dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view){}` to do whatever you want when click day. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick

Comment: ADyson, Sorry for my unclear discription. Yes, you're right, user should go to a different link, when they click on different event.

Comment: In that case you can just do as per the end of my last comment